# How to sum values in a row if you want to use the last non-null value in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

**Excel 365**

Suppose I have the excel table as below:

| Date | Bank Account 1 | Bank Account 2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | £100 |  |  |
| 05/01/2023 |  | £678 |  |
| 09/01/2023 | £100 |  |  |
| 22/01/2023 |  | £821 |  |

The Bank Account 1 & 2 columns show the balance for that account on a particular date. I can't be guaranteed to have the data for each account on all dates - in fact, it would be rare for me to have both. I don't control or own this data or the accounts.

How would I get the total column to show the total of both bank accounts? I realise I could duplicate the data from row 1 in row 2 but I'd rather not as is would suggest that £100 was accurate for Bank Account 1 on 05/01/2023. I want my total column to essentially indicate the sum off all bank accounts using the last known data.

Ideally I'd want to see the following:

| Date | Bank Account 1 | Bank Account 2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | £100 |  | £100 |
| 05/01/2023 |  | £678 | £778 |
| 09/01/2023 | £100 |  | £778 |
| 22/01/2023 |  | £821 | £921 |

FWIW The goal here is that I've created a line chart from this table and I want 3 lines on it - one for each account and one for the total - if there are better ways to do this then I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Which Excel version? In Excel 365 this is fairly easy, using dynamic arrays. (e.g. enter `=XLOOKUP(TRUE,D$2:D2<>"",D$2:D2,,,-1)` into F2)

Comment: It is 365! Thanks - let me try this.

Comment: @Paul that's great - I can make that work for me. If you add as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 365 this is fairly easy, using dynamic arrays.

For instance, if you have a list of values in column D, you can enter `=XLOOKUP(TRUE,D$2:D2<>"",D$2:D2,,,-1)` into F2, and pull down.

The condition creates a dynamic list of true/false flags to mark whether the value in de D column was not empty; the lookup will then retrieve the first value from that column for which the flag is True, starting from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

An extension for more than 1 account:
[image: Accounts]